# How to interpret this parameter meaning

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

What does the followin way to write a parameter mean?

```
int CGame::iGetPlayerABSStatus(int iWhatH, int iRecvH, BOOL & bTransparentInvi)
```

This part: "BOOL & bTransparentInvi"

I took this from old source code of a visual 6.0 project.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means argument `bTransparentInvi` is a reference to the `BOOL` data type.

Don't get confused with the placement of the `&` operator. It's the same as writing `BOOL& bTransparentInvi`.

Comment: I still do not understand, which means that the operator is in the middle of both? What is that way of programming used for?

Comment: @MartinLopez Please refer reference usage from your favorite C++ book. http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1870232 might help, if you don't have one.

Comment: @MartinLopez Stack Overflow is not a good place to learn the fundamentals of the language.  As P0W says - get a book.